Safari debugger keyboard shortcut customizable
Is it possible to customize the keyboard shortcuts in Safari, when debugger is running?
I'd like to have the same shortcuts in all IDEs.
At this moment, with Sonoma 14.5 and Safari 17.5 (19618.2.12.11.6) is not possible: I have not found any setup to do this
